# indexedDB item store was not created

Tags: javascript

I created this indexedDB database but the item store was not created and I couldn't find solutions

```
const IDBRequest = indexedDB.open("MyDatabase", 1);

IDBRequest.addEventListener("upgradeneeded",()=>{
    const db = IDBRequest.result;
    db.createObjectStore("nombres",{
        autoIncrement: true
    });
}) 

IDBRequest.addEventListener("success",()=>{
    console.log("todo salió correctamente");
})

IDBRequest.addEventListener("error",()=>{
    console.log("ocurrió un error al abrir de la base de datos")
})
```

It didn't work, in the browser console I only see the database but the object store called "names".

Answer (score 1):

**Note: be sure you are opening database with a version number higher than before! unless this event never fires!**

change this part:

```
IDBRequest.addEventListener("upgradeneeded",()=>{
    const db = IDBRequest.result;
    db.createObjectStore("nombres",{
        autoIncrement: true
    });
})
```

To this:

```
IDBRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
    const db = event.target.result;
    db.createObjectStore("numbres",{
        autoIncrement: true
    });
};
```